# How to switch to this frame

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a frame but always get this error below:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="esquerda"]
```

My code:

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://ndspx13/")

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('esquerda'))
```

I'm trying to get [this frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tARoH.png).

Answer (score 0):

a find the solution adding some lines of code. 
Look:

```
import time, re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://ndspx13/")
browser.maximize_window()

#browser.implicitly_wait(3);

browser.switch_to.parent_frame()
browser.switch_to.frame(0)
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Servidor x IP").click()
```